# Import file with : separators into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've multiple `TXT` files that contain columns in the following format:

`id:category:topic:date`

They're all lined up under one another. i.e.

`1:category:topic:date`

`2:category:topic:date`

`3:category:topic:date`

is it possible to `import` this file into my `MySQL` database?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @RasmusBoie mind sharing?

Comment: MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) allows you to specify the delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With PHPMyAdmin

On the import tab, you can upload a CSV file. Upload your file, select format 'CSV', and set:

- Columns separated with: `:`
- Columns enclosed with: (empty)

### With PHP

You can write a small PHP program to do that. First, read in the file:

```
$fh = fopen('the-file.txt', 'r');
```

Now, `$fh` is a handler to read the-file.txt. Now we can use `fgetcsv()`:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ':', '')) !== false) {
    // insert data in database
}
```

`$data` is an array of all the data in the record.

---

An example with PDO and a prepared statement:

```
// prepare the statement to insert a new record
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `some_table` (`id`, `category`, `topic`, `date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
// read the file
$fh = fopen('the-file.txt', 'r');
while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ':', '')) !== false) {
    $stmt->execute($data);
}
```

This would assume the column names are 'id', 'category', 'topic' and 'date'.

The number `1000` is the max line length. You can set it to 0, for no maximum length, but this is slightly slower. See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for more information.

Comment: is there not a faster method using i.e. `phpmyadmin`? We are talking about 10M+ lines..

Comment: @Removed ah, I was confused because you used the 'php' tag. I modified the answer.

Comment: why not fgetcsv() with a `:` delimiter

Comment: @MarkBaker I didn't know the function existed, thanks.

Comment: @CamilStaps I get the error "Invalid parameter for CSV import: Columns escaped with" should I use `"` even though that is not how they're escaped?